# Angularjs-error on ng-click: Args is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a basic directive with the following code:

```
    app.directive('selectValues', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                field: '=',
                values: '=',
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs)
            {
                //Get Attributes
                attrs.$observe('modalid', function (value) {
                    scope.modalid = value;
                });
                scope.$watch('field', function (value) {
                    scope.selectedValue = scope.field;
                });
                scope.UpdateValue = new function () {
                    console.log(scope.selectedValue);
                    scope.field= scope.selectedValue;
                };
            },
            template:'<div>' +
                '<div id="{{modalid}}" class="modal">' +
                    '<div class="Content">' +
                        '<form action="#">' +
                           // Some form is displayed here
                        '</form>' +
                    '</div>' +
               '<div class="menu">' +
                        '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="saveButton" ng-click="UpdateValue()">Bewaren</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
               '</div></div>'

    }
});
```

The error occurs when clicking my `savebutton`. Even the `console.log` is never called. Everything else seems to work as expected. And i can't find anything using google (most reference C# or java errors).

Anyone got an idea?

**Full Error details:**

```
    Error: args is null $parseFunctionCall@http://***/***/scripts/angular.js:12333:1 
ngEventHandler/</callback@http://***/***/scripts/angular.js:22949:17 
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://***/***/scripts/angular.js:14383:16 
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://***/***/scripts/angular.js:14482:18 
ngEventHandler/<@http://***/***/scripts/angular.js:22954:17 
m.event.dispatch@http://***/***/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:8:9614 
m.event.add/r.handle@http://***/***/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:8:5676


return logFn.apply(console, args);
```

**Note:**
The stars hide my personal data.

Thanx for the assist

Comment: can you create a fiddle of it

Comment: @NaeemShaikh. I'll try to get one up as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `new` before the `function` that you assign to `scope.UpdateValue`:

```
scope.UpdateValue = function () {
                       console.log(scope.selectedValue);
                       scope.field= scope.selectedValue;
                    };
```

Comment: Yep you were right. Right now i'm trying to determine the reason why I put a `new` there. I don't understand how I could have made such an basic mistake...